# Package dependency issue, not sure safest way to proceed

Tags: yum, rhel7, zfsonlinux, kernel-modules

I am running into a package dependency issue. Can someone help make sense of how to resolve this?

**Q** What steps do i need to take when it says `Requires: zfs-kmod = 0.7.7
           Available: kmod-zfs-0.6.5.11-1.el7_4.x86_64 (zfs-kmod)` for e.g.   do I need to remove them, are they in cache and the cache needs to be cleaned?

What triggered this, is I'm using `zfsonlinux`, and moving from DKMS to [Kabi Tracking method](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/wiki/RHEL-and-CentOS#kabi-tracking-kmod).  I have already removed DKMS modules [per the docs](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/wiki/RHEL-and-CentOS#switching-from-dkms-to-kabi-tracking-kmod), which seems to go off without a hitch, however something along the lines got out of sync.

/etc/yum.repos.d/zfs.repo

```
  1 [zfs]
  2 name=ZFS on Linux for EL7 - dkms
  3 baseurl=http://download.zfsonlinux.org/epel/7.4/$basearch/
  4 enabled=0
  5 metadata_expire=7d
  6 gpgcheck=1
  7 gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-zfsonlinux
  8
  9 [zfs-kmod]
 10 name=ZFS on Linux for EL7 - kmod
 11 baseurl=http://download.zfsonlinux.org/epel/7.4/kmod/$basearch/
 12 enabled=1
 13 metadata_expire=7d
 14 gpgcheck=1
 15 gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-zfsonlinux
 ...
```

When I try to install:

```
 $ sudo yum install zfs
    Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
    Repository nodesource is listed more than once in the configuration
    Repository nodesource-source is listed more than once in the configuration
    Resolving Dependencies
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package zfs.x86_64 0:0.7.7-1.el7_4 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: zfs-kmod = 0.7.7 for package: zfs-0.7.7-1.el7_4.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: spl = 0.7.7 for package: zfs-0.7.7-1.el7_4.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: libzpool2 = 0.7.7 for package: zfs-0.7.7-1.el7_4.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: libzfs2 = 0.7.7 for package: zfs-0.7.7-1.el7_4.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: libuutil1 = 0.7.7 for package: zfs-0.7.7-1.el7_4.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: libnvpair1 = 0.7.7 for package: zfs-0.7.7-1.el7_4.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: libzpool.so.2()(64bit) for package: zfs-0.7.7-1.el7_4.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: libzfs_core.so.1()(64bit) for package: zfs-0.7.7-1.el7_4.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: libzfs.so.2()(64bit) for package: zfs-0.7.7-1.el7_4.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: libuutil.so.1()(64bit) for package: zfs-0.7.7-1.el7_4.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: libnvpair.so.1()(64bit) for package: zfs-0.7.7-1.el7_4.x86_64
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package libnvpair1.x86_64 0:0.7.7-1.el7_4 will be installed
    ---> Package libuutil1.x86_64 0:0.7.7-1.el7_4 will be installed
    ---> Package libzfs2.x86_64 0:0.7.7-1.el7_4 will be installed
    ---> Package libzpool2.x86_64 0:0.7.7-1.el7_4 will be installed
    ---> Package spl.x86_64 0:0.7.7-1.el7_4 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: spl-kmod = 0.7.7 for package: spl-0.7.7-1.el7_4.x86_64
    ---> Package zfs.x86_64 0:0.7.7-1.el7_4 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: zfs-kmod = 0.7.7 for package: zfs-0.7.7-1.el7_4.x86_64
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package kmod-spl.x86_64 0:0.7.7-1.el7_4 will be installed
    ---> Package zfs.x86_64 0:0.7.7-1.el7_4 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: zfs-kmod = 0.7.7 for package: zfs-0.7.7-1.el7_4.x86_64
    --> Finished Dependency Resolution
    Error: Package: zfs-0.7.7-1.el7_4.x86_64 (zfs-kmod)
               Requires: zfs-kmod = 0.7.7
               Available: kmod-zfs-0.6.5.11-1.el7_4.x86_64 (zfs-kmod)
                   zfs-kmod = 0.6.5.11-1.el7_4
               Available: kmod-zfs-0.7.1-1.el7_4.x86_64 (zfs-kmod)
                   zfs-kmod = 0.7.1-1.el7_4
               Available: kmod-zfs-0.7.2-1.el7_4.x86_64 (zfs-kmod)
                   zfs-kmod = 0.7.2-1.el7_4
               Available: kmod-zfs-0.7.3-1.el7_4.x86_64 (zfs-kmod)
                   zfs-kmod = 0.7.3-1.el7_4
               Available: kmod-zfs-0.7.4-1.el7_4.x86_64 (zfs-kmod)
                   zfs-kmod = 0.7.4-1.el7_4
               Available: kmod-zfs-0.7.4-2.el7_4.x86_64 (zfs-kmod)
                   zfs-kmod = 0.7.4-2.el7_4
               Available: kmod-zfs-0.7.5-1.el7_4.x86_64 (zfs-kmod)
                   zfs-kmod = 0.7.5-1.el7_4
               Available: kmod-zfs-0.7.6-1.el7_4.x86_64 (zfs-kmod)
                   zfs-kmod = 0.7.6-1.el7_4
    **********************************************************************
    yum can be configured to try to resolve such errors by temporarily enabling
    disabled repos and searching for missing dependencies.
    To enable this functionality please set 'notify_only=0' in /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/search-disabled-repos.conf
    **********************************************************************

    Error: Package: zfs-0.7.7-1.el7_4.x86_64 (zfs-kmod)
               Requires: zfs-kmod = 0.7.7
               Available: kmod-zfs-0.6.5.11-1.el7_4.x86_64 (zfs-kmod)
                   zfs-kmod = 0.6.5.11-1.el7_4
               Available: kmod-zfs-0.7.1-1.el7_4.x86_64 (zfs-kmod)
                   zfs-kmod = 0.7.1-1.el7_4
               Available: kmod-zfs-0.7.2-1.el7_4.x86_64 (zfs-kmod)
                   zfs-kmod = 0.7.2-1.el7_4
               Available: kmod-zfs-0.7.3-1.el7_4.x86_64 (zfs-kmod)
                   zfs-kmod = 0.7.3-1.el7_4
               Available: kmod-zfs-0.7.4-1.el7_4.x86_64 (zfs-kmod)
                   zfs-kmod = 0.7.4-1.el7_4
               Available: kmod-zfs-0.7.4-2.el7_4.x86_64 (zfs-kmod)
                   zfs-kmod = 0.7.4-2.el7_4
               Available: kmod-zfs-0.7.5-1.el7_4.x86_64 (zfs-kmod)
                   zfs-kmod = 0.7.5-1.el7_4
               Available: kmod-zfs-0.7.6-1.el7_4.x86_64 (zfs-kmod)
                   zfs-kmod = 0.7.6-1.el7_4
     You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
     You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

It looked like `--skip-broken` would work, when i tried it, but i didnt let it complete, didnt say yes to it.

**Q** I'm not sure what `rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest` is, would that help?

**Q** I Did try to temporarily enable disabled repos, that didnt work.

Here is what I see installed now: (currently nothing showing up for dkms, spl, zfs)

```
$ sudo yum list installed | grep zfs
Repository nodesource is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository nodesource-source is listed more than once in the configuration

$ sudo yum list installed | grep kmod
Repository nodesource is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository nodesource-source is listed more than once in the configuration
kmod.x86_64                      20-15.el7_4.7           @rhel-7-server-rpms
kmod-libs.x86_64                 20-15.el7_4.7           @rhel-7-server-rpms
python-kmod.x86_64               0.9-4.el7               @anaconda/7.2
```

Even when I install zfs-release `sudo yum install http://download.zfsonlinux.org/epel/zfs-release.el7_4.noarch.rpm` I get the same kmod package error.

Another couple steps i took, which didnt help is the following, but i still have the same symptoms.

```
$ sudo yum autoremove
$ sudo yum clean metadata
```

Im not sure how to repair this, so that i can regain ZSF file access.

**Q** How  should I proceed?

Comment: Wow, I just stumbled across this concindentally within 12 hours of its posting.  https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/7315
It appears that there is an issue in the `zfs-kmod` package, unless I misunderstoor that.

Comment: The repo doesn't appear to have been updated.